# How to reshape 3D numpy array <10,3,2> to 4D array <10,1,3,2>?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have the following numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

np.ones((10, 3, 2))
```

and I need to reshape it to `<10,1,3,2>`.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```py
np.ones((10, 3, 2)).reshape([10,1,3,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
x = np.ones((10, 3, 2))
# in place
x.shape = (10,1,3,2)
```

```py
# new view
x.reshape((10,1,3,2))
```

```py
# Add new axis
x[:, np.newaxis, :, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others mentioned, you can `.reshape` it. An alternative is to use `np.newaxis` or `np.expand_dims` like this:

```
arr = np.ones((10, 3, 2))

arr1 = arr[:, np.newaxis, ...]
print(arr1.shape)  # (10, 1, 3, 2)

arr2 = np.expand_dims(arr, 1)
print(arr2.shape)  # (10, 1, 3, 2)

# check if the two arrays are equal
print(np.array_equal(arr1, arr2))  # True
```